# Phalcon Volt check_field with if else statement for checked

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I have a checkbox im trying to build in Volt:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="myClass" data-size="small" data-type="{{ type.getType() }}">
```

So now i would normally write it like this

```
{{ check_field( 'class':'my class', 'data-size':'small', 'data-model-pk': ''~ AclGroup.id_group ) }}'
```

However i would like to do something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="myClass" {% if AclGroup.flg_active == 1 %} checked="" {% endif %} data-size="small" data-type="{{ type.getType() }}">
```

But i have no idea how to do a statement inside `{{ }}`

I tried breaking out of the `{{ }}{% %}{{ }}` and a bunch of other stuff but i cant find any documentation that covers it and nothing i tried works. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a html version of what you want to achieve

Comment: I think that if `AclGroup.flg_active` is Boolean you can just use that like `'checked' : AclGroup.flg_active`. Phalcon will not add the `checked` attribute is it is false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always leave it as you have given in your example - Volt is, at times, just a nice way to produce Html after all.

However, I would do this

```
{% if AclGroup.flg_acive == 1 %}
    {{ check_field( 'class':'my class', 'checked': "", 'data-size':'small', 'data-type': type.getType() ) }}
{% else %}
    {{ check_field( 'class':'my class', 'data-size':'small', 'data-type': type.getType() ) }}
{% endif %}
```

There is no way to use an `if` statement inside the `echo` - `{{...}}` - that I am aware of, so you need to have 2 echos and use and `if-else` instead.

Answer (score 4):

One line code:

```
{{ check_field( 'class':'my class', 'data-size':'small', 'data-model-pk':  AclGroup.id_group, 'checked':(AclGroup.flg_acive == 1 ? true : null) ) }}'
```

Also this would work, interestingly:

```
{{ check_field( 'class':'my class', 'data-size':'small', 'data-model-pk':  AclGroup.id_group, 'checked':(AclGroup.flg_acive == 1 ? false : null) ) }}'
```

But I think the first is more logical.

Comment: Upvoted as this should be the accepted answer really, because it demonstrates the correct use of the checkbox tag checked method. Note that `null` must be used, because an empty string, 0 or `false` will always result in the checkbox being checked.